# Child div doesnt take full width in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dhtml

I have this structure in a page

```
    <div style="float: right">
        <div>
            <label>
                Test type</label>
            <select id="selTest1">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                Test category</label>
            <select id="selTestCat">
                <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
            </select>
        </div>


        <div style="text-align: right; width: 100%;">
            <a style="margin-right:0px;" href="Nothing.aspx" class="button" id="btnTest">Select</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="hdTest1" runat="server" type="hidden" />
            <input id="hdnTest2" runat="server" type="hidden" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

everything is aligned properly in IE7
except

```
<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%;">
    <a style="margin-right:0px;" href="Nothing.aspx" class="button" id="btnTest">Select</a>
</div>
```

in IE8 and other browsers, this div also takes the whole width, and the button is aligned to the right.
But in IE7 the button's div takes the width of the button only.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying display:inline to your button. I have done it for you below, see if it works:

```
 <div style="float: right">
        <div>
            <label>
                Test type</label>
            <select id="selTest1">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                Test category</label>
            <select id="selTestCat">
                <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
            </select>
        </div>


        <div style="text-align: right; width: 100%;">
            <a style="margin-right:0px; display:inline;" href="Nothing.aspx" class="button" id="btnTest">Select</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="hdTest1" runat="server" type="hidden" />
            <input id="hdnTest2" runat="server" type="hidden" />
        </div>
    </div>
```